# Get Angular component instance of component that was opened via MatDialog in tests

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, dom, jestjs

In an Angular project using Jest as a test runner, I am writing a component test for component **Parent**. **Parent** internally causes a dialog to open using an injected `MatDialog`; that dialog displays component **Child**.

The component test should contain the following behavior:

1. Create an instance of **Parent**.
2. Perform the triggers that cause **Parent** to open the dialog.
3. Verify that an instance of **Child** has been created with the correct parameters.

The only solution I am aware of is to mock `MatDialog.open` with a spy and verify a call to that method. However, I would prefer if I could find the instance of **Child** that was created in the DOM and perform my verification on that object. Is there a way to do this?

Notably, using `fixture.debugElement.query` (with `fixture` being of type `ComponentFixture<Parent>`) does not work, probably because **Child** is not created in the subtree of **Parent**.